# How to properly instantiate the WePay Object in Python?

Tags: flask, payment-processing

I am trying to get an access token to do things on the users behalf and I have been reading their documentation and following this (https://www.wepay.com/developer/create_accounts/oauth2) tutorial on their site.

At first, I tried to directly use a GET request with the parameters encoded in the URL, however I kept getting a 401 so then I tried their tutorial, now this error in the console:

```
in add_merchant_token
    wepay = WePay(production, None)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I am able to get the 'code' for retrieving the token, I just can't for the life of me figure out how to get the actual token.

Code:

```
code = request.args.get('code')
redirect_uri = "http://localhost:5000/add_merchant_token"

# application settings
client_id = XXXXXX
client_secret = 'XXXXXX'
production = False

wepay = WePay(production, None)

# create an account for a user
response = wepay.get_token(redirect_uri, client_id, client_secret, code)

# display the response
print response

return response
```

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Marcus/Developer/GitHub/subbitt/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/Marcus/Developer/GitHub/subbitt/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/Marcus/Developer/GitHub/subbitt/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/Marcus/Developer/GitHub/subbitt/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/Marcus/Developer/GitHub/subbitt/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/Marcus/Developer/GitHub/subbitt/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/Marcus/Developer/GitHub/subbitt/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/Marcus/Developer/GitHub/subbitt/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/Marcus/Developer/GitHub/subbitt/app/views.py", line 622, in add_merchant_token
    wepay = WePay(production, None)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: What is the full stacktrace? What does your import look like? `from wepay import WePay; WePay(False, None)` works for me.

Comment: from wepay import WePay

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to do it using a third party [Python WePay SDK](https://github.com/lehins/python-wepay)

```
from wepay import WePay
from wepay.exceptions import WePayHTTPError, WePayConnectionError

# application settings
CLIENT_ID = XXXXXX
CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXX'
PRODUCTION = False
DEFAULT_SCOPE = "manage_accounts,collect_payments,view_user," \
                "preapprove_payments,manage_subscriptions,send_money"
wepay = WePay(production=PRODUCTION)

redirect_uri = "http://localhost:5000/add_merchant_token"
url = wepay.oauth2.authorize(CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri, DEFAULT_SCOPE, 
                             user_name="John Doe", user_email="john@example.com")
# send user to that `url` and then get code from the redirected url 
# query string. Note if 'error' is in a query, handle it appropriately
...
code = request.args.get('code')

# create an account for a user
try:
    response = wepay.oauth2.token(CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri, CLIENT_SECRET, code)
    access_token = response['access_token']
    # display the response
    print response
except WePayHTTPError as exc:
    if exc.error_code == 1012:
        print "code has expired"
    print exc
except WePayConnectionError as exc:
    print exc
    # problem with connecting to wepay, retry api call a bit later
```